# Open a file without supplying the path directly

Tags: python

let's say that I have the following class:

```
class FileName(object):
 def __init__(self,pathName):
   self.pathName = pathName

 def __repr__(self):
   return self.pathName

someFile = FileName(r'c:\users\sarith\a.txt')
```

Now I am aware that I can get the details of this file using `os.stat(someFile.pathName)` or using `os.stat(str(someFile))`. Is there a way  through which I can get the details by just doing `os.stat(someFile)`. More specifically, I mean is there a function that I could override such that when the instance of `FileName` is called by functions such as `open`, it returns the `pathName` attribute?

Comment: .... Why is such functionality not already part of the class?

Comment: Yes, add like a `getStat` method or something

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think my example overshadowed what I was trying to ask. I want to supply the instance as a parameter directly for any operation that might require access to the filepath. Right now, I get a "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer" error when I do that.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the kind of thing you'd expect to exist, but many such functions actually do recognize an [`__fspath__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike), at least on Python 3.6:

```
class FileName(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    def __fspath__(self):
        return self.path

# Actually works!
os.stat(FileName('/whatever'))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option that may work is to just inherit from `str`:

```
In [5]: class FileName(str):
   ...:  def __init__(self,pathName):
   ...:    self.pathName = pathName
   ...:
   ...:  def __repr__(self):
   ...:    return self.pathName
   ...:

In [6]: os.stat(FileName("./__init__.py"))
Out[6]: posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=26082240, st_dev=16777220, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=203, st_atime=1489773922, st_mtime=1487777486, st_ctime=1487777486)

In [7]: os.stat("./__init__.py")
Out[7]: posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=26082240, st_dev=16777220, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=203, st_atime=1489773922, st_mtime=1487777486, st_ctime=1487777486)
```

Comment: This gets really confusing really fast when some things are using the inherited `str` structure and some things are using the `pathName` attribute you defined. For example, if you make `__init__` set `self.pathName = pathName + '.txt'`, things like `open` or `os.stat` won't see the `.txt`.